# Error al ejecutar script bash en GitHub Actions

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

Llevo un par de días sin lograr resolvver un error que me lanza GitHub Actions cuando intento ejecutar el siguiente script bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

declare -A versionNameUpdateLevels=(["major"]=0 ["minor"]=1 ["security"]=2)

variant=${VARIANT,,}
shouldUpdateVersionName=${SHOULD_UPDATE_VERSION_NAME}
versionNameUpdateLevel=${VERSION_NAME_UPDATE_LEVEL,,}
versionFile="${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/version.gradle"

echo "Verifying current version info"

mapfile -t < ${versionFile}

IFS=":" read -a previousVersionCodeArray <<<${MAPFILE[2]}
previousVersionCode=${previousVersionCodeArray[1]:1:-1}

IFS=":" read -a previousVersionNameArray <<<${MAPFILE[3]}
previousVersionName=${previousVersionNameArray[1]:2:-1}

echo ::set-output name=previous-version-code::"${previousVersionCode}"
echo ::set-output name=previous-version-name::"${previousVersionName}"

if [[ "${variant}" == "debug" ]]; then
  echo "Debug variants should not be updated"
  exit 0
fi

echo "Updating version info"

if [[ "${shouldUpdateVersionName}" == true ]]; then
  if ! [[ -n "${versionNameUpdateLevels[$versionNameUpdateLevel]}" ]]; then
    echo "Invalid versionNameUpdateLevel, possible values are 'security', 'minor' or 'major'"
    exit 1
  fi
  fi

updatedVersionCode="$((previousVersionCode+1))"

IFS="." read -a versionNameArray <<<${previousVersionName}
majorLevel=${versionNameArray[0]}
minorLevel=${versionNameArray[1]}
securityLevel=${versionNameArray[2]}
if [[ "${versionNameUpdateLevel}" == "major" ]]; then
  majorLevel=$((majorLevel+1))
  minorLevel=0
  securityLevel=0
elif [[ "${versionNameUpdateLevel}" == "minor" ]]; then
  minorLevel=$((minorLevel+1))
  securityLevel=0
else
  securityLevel=$((securityLevel+1))
fi
updatedVersionName="${majorLevel}.${minorLevel}.${securityLevel}"

rm -rf ${versionFile}

touch ${versionFile}
echo "ext {" >> ${versionFile}
echo "    app = [" >> ${versionFile}
echo "        versionCode: ${updatedVersionCode}," >> ${versionFile}
echo "        versionName: \"${updatedVersionName}\"" >> ${versionFile}
echo "    ]" >> ${versionFile}
echo "}" >> ${versionFile}

echo ::set-output name=updated-version-code::"${updatedVersionCode}"
echo ::set-output name=updated-version-name="${updatedVersionName}"

commitMsg="${variant~} version cut ${updatedVersionName} build ${updatedVersionCode}"
echo ::set-output name=version-info-commit-msg::"${commitMsg}"

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

El archivo version.gradle que intento generar se debe ve así:

```
ext {
    app = [
        versionCode: ###,
        versionName: "#.#.#"
    ]
}
```

Logro ejecutar el script sin problemas desde mi workflow pero me da este error:

> /home/runner/work/_temp/71abcf83-5b27-43c7-aca0-66c1bdab4a2a.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `]'
> Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

Ya revisé todos los corchetes ']' de mi script y no veo nada mal, igual simulé las env localmente y el script si funciona como debe usando WSL2 y Ubuntu 2020.4, hay algo que esté pasando por alto?

Answer (score 0):

Según [shellsheck](https://www.shellcheck.net), tu script se ve bien en general salvo el hecho de que sería mejor si las variables las pusieras entrecomilladas con comillas dobles. Intenta ver si no te están inyectando un input raro para evitar el word splitting, osea, entrecomilla.

También revisa la versión de tu shell. Revisa que sea una versión actualizada de Bash.

Trato de adivinar porque todo se ve bien.